# Android - Unexpected Top Level Exception on Twitter Integration

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dex

My project is completely fine until I tried to implement **Twitter Sharing**. I've been followed this [step by step guide](https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/android/integrating) until I have my API KEY. But when I was trying to run my app, I got this error:

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 --output C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\activation-37a6940c1606740f9a286fda46071e5a6d0c13fc.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\additionnal-896f392699ed9152a928c8c8f9965367c30cc751.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\android-async-http-1.4.4-109da6f264e4fce4126d3b2c5fd05b9f2c521325.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\android-smart-image-view-1.0.0-d13245982190f7e96ca103151f6486e5a56ca9f1.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\bolts-android-1.1.4-8fe340c1ef6062ca7f09c19106784e65f4d7bc12.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-0586947e468328837cd89c4c3ca2ddc7d4edf1bd.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-06498e0bec0d33c546efc014e1491923d98298b6.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-190ea8a5019ebbc309b5c2dd9c461e2c63d2ad6f.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-25a2320035a60e77d98bf97436c3fe8ebcbc3eb0.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-39ba001ec840ebff51786732ff59cbfbbc8ed111.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-4ab49831029b57a6fe48c36bbda44f21d2041622.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-6ba347ea7241709c97daecef6bbc1bba78a97814.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-7821a252ac16e47c2c646536c3df76ae406ab61e.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-7a849aad0b644371b48a1832e9d97cfaf4b1fe0b.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-9a85028e6d314fe7ee66ccb42a544ccc4328b713.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-9cfd8f89e025930361299a07e0e6f655b84cc8b0.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-bd75c21ef8c770ccb1e09893e7c80443e2b87935.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-c186d5277aac13b1168d2fe2fa531f17e084dbb0.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-c7923d00d7f0df089fa523bc30fffed023061642.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-cbb3428cbad0ea44ba43f3f89039efb7c9bb0f93.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-ec5d5b224cd52187f7df27fca55d3c3175c1ef4c.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\commons-codec-1.5-a99e9399152eac6781e4e1c56556efed63df5951.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\commons-lang3-3.1-934a968710081f10f9a4ec9787d826548a4e4598.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\core-2.2-7efb9b74966dfaac2b43fbc4036da8b3eb03e1e7.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\CWAC-SackOfViewsAdapter-4def35247a8036435022da92494ba559362c8665.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\gson-2.2.4-282759dc6c0489536afc1518a9a3dd4618388c1b.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-39fbf5b7699385735d3e90aa04307f740dcdea1f.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-af61375739f819dc2d75dbcf57a19eed29c23e96.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\ksoap2-android-assembly-3.2.0-jar-with-dependencies-2eb01770014a77a8ca0186cf7bda57de5f449dfe.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\mail-33af8e1841b9f3fc22ce9b38d308d70ce094b924.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\picasso-2.3.2-2a0f04bc510fe6de1aca757462e92fdf913f620d.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\picasso-2.3.4-23fd634f031fd6dec8bce687fd873f8a963d7fbf.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\retrofit-1.6.1-b32a09ecfcd191796e0223459439c0f65c573d8e.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-64e830d146342acfc335bdcbbf1416619dfd86a2.jar C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\TelkomVision\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\universal-image-loader-1.9.1-with-sources-143b6e9fad398c63876b918468c81d6d01105449.jar
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/squareup/picasso/Action$RequestWeakReference;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)`

Here is my `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-smart-image-view-1.0.0')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1-with-sources')
    compile 'com.f2prateek.progressbutton:progressbutton:2.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:0.7.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

As a quick fix, I tried to add this on my `build.gradle`:

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

But it has some *side effect* (such as slower build). Can someone explain why I get this error, and what is the correct solution?

Comment: Actually, I did some workaround and I manage to fix my problem. However, I'm not sure which changes do the fix. That's why I don't post any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve the error by adding following lines in build.gradle file below

```
apply plugin: 'android'

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.picasso', module: 'picasso'
}
```

Comment: Worked for when Picasso was causing my build to barf